# How to call two functions onClick() react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `component` that looks like this

```
class Test extends React.Component {
   onClick() {
       alert("I am a Component")
   }

   render() { 
      const { fromContainer } = this.props
      return (
         <a href="#" onClick={ this.onClick }>Test Link</a>
      );
   }
}
```

In my `container` I connect `Test` to the `Store`. I need to call two functions on the `onClick`. One function as defined in the `component` itself (`onClick()` with `alert()`, the other one is the function `fromContainer` which is an `action`, going through the `reducer` etc.

How do I make the function `fromContainer` known to the component. 
When only one function is called its:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
   render() { 
      const { fromContainer } = this.props
      return (
         <a href="#" onClick={ fromContainer }>Test Link</a>
      );
   }
}
```

and thats it. But it does not work with two functions, that are defined in different "places".

Comment: You do know that `this.onClick` in your first version will loose it context no? There is a great potential benefit for using arrow functions here, like `() => this.onClick()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 class Test extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super()
     this.test = this.test.bind(this)
   }

   test() {
     this.props.fromContainer();
     //call other function here
   }

   render() {
     const { fromContainer } = this.props
     return (
         <a href = "#" onClick = { this.test }> Test Link </a>
     );
   }
 }
```

please try this

Comment: constructor () {
     super()
      this. test = this. test.bind(this)
    }
please bind the function name in constructor

Comment: thats it. more information here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html (just got pointed towards it)

Comment: You could also use the arrow function, imho, it's nicer and keeps the context correctly

Comment: @Icepickle How would I use arrowfunctions here?

Comment: @Stophface Just by removing the bind from the constructor and use `<a href="#" onClick={()=>this.test()}>`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your local-to-component onClick and from-container onClick into a single function.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
    localOnClick() {
       alert('local on click');
    }
    
    onClick() {
      const { fromContainer } = this.props;
      localOnClick();
      fromContainer();
    }
    
    render() { 
       return (
          <a href="#" onClick={ this.onClick.bind(this) }>Test Link</a>
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: Check again now with the edit please, I added a binding to `this` on the onclick

Answer (score 0):

This is code is NOT tested. I just made it up on a whim. If I got you right, I think you just need to use the `Container` you wrapped your `Component` with instead of the `Component` itself (in this case your `Test` component) like so:

```
// action.js ====================
const fromContainer = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'DO_SOMETHING' })
}

export default fromContainer;

// reducer.js ===============================
export default (state=[], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case 'DO_SOMETHING':
        return {...state, { newField: 'newValue' } };
    default: return state;
  }
}

// Container.js ==============================
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => state.reducer;

export default Container = connect(mapStateToProps, { fromContainer })(Component);

// Component ===============================
class Component extends React.Component {
   onClick() {
       this.props.fromContainer();
   }

   render() { 
      return (
         <a href="#" onClick={ this.onClick.bind(this) }>Test Link</a>
      );
   }
}

// and in your routes (just for example react-router v3.0.2) ==============
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store'; // assuming your store is on the same directory

import Container from './Container'; // instead of using the Component, you need to use Container instead.

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Container}></Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

Hope this helps even just a little bit. ^^,